# checking completion of void async method

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

I have an event handler (from a timer) that redraws every x milliseconds.

Even though it is (apparently) not best practice to use async void methods, this is apparently not true for event handlers since the developer doesn't call them from other methods.

My problem is I've noticed that when the processor has a heavy workload (background tasks, etc), overlapping calls to redraw are made.

I've been able to get around this by setting a flag (bool variable) to indicate the drawing is complete (and not calling my draw method unless this flag is true), but I've heard Windows store apps can be rejected for polling on async activity.

```
private void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    if (drawingFinished == true)
    {
        drawingFinished = false;

        // drawingFinished set to true at the end of this method
        DrawVideoFrame();    
    }
}
```

Also, you can't add locks to async methods.

What is best practice here? How should I go about this?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but instead of using a Boolean flag, you could simply cache the task and check if it is completed.  What exactly does DrawVideoFrame actually do?

Comment: Interesting idea, pm_2. I would think I couldn't get the Task until the method that returns the task has completed.

Comment: No - you can just create the task as a variable and use it later on in the process flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My method looks more like this now:

```
private void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    _timer.Stop();

    DrawVideoFrame();    // calls timer.Start() as one the last line
}
```

I see pro's and con's to this solution:

Pros: (1) It feels less like a kludge (sp?). (2) Microsoft has, uh, less grounds to reject my app because I'm not checking a completion condition. (3) My drawing method is *definitely* not getting interrupted now. (4) Despite my best efforts it is working as desired ;)

Cons: I'm not really scheduling when the frames are drawn anymore. So instead of setting the timeout for 1000 ms and thinking it will get called (at most) 1 Hz, high-end machines will see a faster number of frames (since the only fixed length of time is between calls to DrawVideoFrame()). I guess that is the nature of surfing the async wave, so to speak.

Comment: I'm doing something similar to this in a program I wrote a while back.  If you want to get closer to 1Hz, you can track the time since the last frame and modify timer value accordingly. For example, if DrawVideoFrame took 20ms set the timer to 1000 - 20 prior to starting it. That will compensate for the varying speed/load on the machine to some extent. It won't be perfect, but it will get closer.

Comment: @WayneTanner: I'll have to chew on that. The benefit seems to be consistency. The downside is this: what if it takes longer than 1000 ms? Obviously you can't have a negative wait time. If you clamp it to >= 0 you have some consistency, but not necessarily always. And if the time changes significantly between frames ... still, I suppose it's better than nothing.

Comment: You are correct, it is an issue if your frame time is > 1000ms. It happened to me and I just clamped to 0 for the delay and made a best effort to maintain the target frame rate. For what I was doing absolute frame rate wasn't critical so it was acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx from the March 2013 issue of MSDN Magazine? The first section of the article discusses async event handlers to some extent. It isn't a direct solution to your problem, but it may give you a hint.